# Асинхронность в js

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Хочу визуализировать пузырьковую сортировку в JS в учебных целях. 
Суть в том, чтобы во время прохождения по элементам массива и их сравнении, функция "замораживалась".
Увы, SetTimeout не подходит, т.к. не выполняет аналог функции sleep(), как в других языках, а выполняется независимо от работы функции сортировки.
Как обойти этот нюанс?

Comment: @pandal, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, делайте ассинхронную сортировку, это же просто:

- http://www.public.asu.edu/~aiadicic/sort.html#quicksort
- http://visualgo.net/sorting.html
- http://bl.ocks.org/andrewringler/3809399
- ну и так далее